# Let $\mathcal{U}(4)$ be a subspace of $\mathcal{P}(4)$ consisting of all polynomials that are even functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathcal{U}(4)$ be a subspace of $\mathcal{P}(4)$ consisting of polynomials that are even functions. Show that there exists a subspace $W \subset \mathcal{P}(4)$ such that $$\mathcal{P}(4) = \mathcal{U}(4) \oplus W.$$

How do I approach this problem? I'm not certain where I should start. I know that a function $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is even if $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: This holds for any subspace of any vectorspace.

Comment: Hint: Before you can answer a question, you have to understand it.

Comment: I just hate getting "hints" for answers if the user is not going to participate in a bit of discussion in the comments. This isn't homework.

Comment: Whether or not it is homework, it is clearly an exercise you have been given in some context (whether or not you will be graded on it or anyone will ever see your attempted solution is irrelevant). Hence, just getting a full solution will not help you learn as much as getting hints will.

Comment: Sure, mindlessly reading a solutions manual would not be beneficial to an individual's learning. But what's so wrong with a complete solution to a problem I have already struggled with? Doesn't build enough character? I find that I learn plenty from complete solutions. Hints are fine too, but a "hint" should not be an excuse for a skimpy answer to gain quick reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* $$\begin{align} f(x) = \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2} + \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}. \end{align} $$

Comment: Do I just assign $\begin{align} W = \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2} \text{ and } \mathcal{U}(4) = \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2} \end{align}$?

Comment: No. The function $\dfrac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$ is odd. You can write every polynomial as the sum of an even function and an odd function.

Comment: If you explain a bit further, I will give you the green check mark. Otherwise, I will leave this question unanswered.

Comment: Do you know what does $\mathcal{P}(4) = \mathcal{U}(4) \oplus W$ mean? It means that every polynomial can uniquely be written as the sum of two elements from $\mathcal{U}(4)$ and $W$, respectively.